# Creating a Dockerfile - docker starts from scratch on each new build

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am trying to build a dockerfile - iteratively adding lines and testing. My understanding was that docker will cache the lines that have already been built and start from the new lines I had added. The case seems to be that it just builds from scratch each time I call build on my container. Is this normal? If not - what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As demas said, if you're simply appending lines, the previous lines will be cached.

However, if anywhere in your Dockerfile you have a line like

```
ADD . /some/path
```

then Docker will assume that that line has changed even if it was only the Dockerfile that changed. So that line and anything after it will never be cached, unless *nothing* in the folder you're adding has changed.

You should be able to see whether this is happening by paying close attention to the output of the `docker build` command.

As a side note: a consequence of this is that if you're building a Dockerfile, you generally want to add the files in the directory as late as possible, doing any preparations beforehand. Of course, you will end up having to do things to your files (like some kind of build process) which is unfortunately hard to cache.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly you can look at Docker as version control system where each line in your Dockerfile is a commit to the container.

If you add new line to your Dockerfile, Docker get the last revision of container and make a new commit.  If you add line on the middle of your Dockerfile, Docker get one of the previous revisions and make new commit to this part of the tree.

Comment: That's what i thought - I am appending to the end of the file on each addition... it's taking ages to build each time!

Comment: It is not depend how are you creating Dockerfile. 1) line by line with build after each line or 2) create all the Dockerfile and use 'build' command once -> result will be the same.  You get one 'commit' for each line of your 'Dockerfile'.  All you can do - combine multiple lines in one (RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade && ...)

Comment: Yes, but should it be building the previous lines already built or should it be getting them from cache?

Comment: It use the state on the 'moment of line' after which you add the new line, as I know.