# I'm trying to make the perfect docker build file, do i need to build it from scratch each time?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

For an assignment the marker requires of me to create a dockerfile to build my project's container, however I have a fairly complex set of tasks I need to have work in the right way together for my dockerfile to be of any use to me, so I am currently building a file that takes 30 minutes each time just to see if minor changes affect the outcome in the right way, so my question is, is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: And you didn't show the dockerfile here?

Comment: my question is about the process, not what is in the dockerfile

Comment: In the absence of a Docker file to review I would refer you to the guidelines documentation: https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/  Another practice I follow is to create base images based on my "technology" stack. That way each application has a very minimal and uncomplicated Dockerfile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Dockerfile best practices](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/#/add-or-copy), or an earlier question might help: [Creating a Dockerfile - docker starts from scratch on each new build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26956796/creating-a-dockerfile-docker-starts-from-scratch-on-each-new-build?rq=1)

In my experience, a full build every time means you're working against docker's caching mechanism, usually by having `COPY . .` early in the Dockerfile.

If the files copied into the image are then used to drive a package manager, or download other sources - try copying just the script or requirements file, then using it, then copying the rest of the sources.

a simplified python example, restated from the best practices link:

```
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
```

With that structure, as long as requirements.txt does not change, the first `COPY` and following `RUN` command use cached layers and rebuilds are much faster.

Answer (score 0):

The first tip is using COPY/ADD for artifacts that need to be download when docker builds.

The second tip is, you can create one Dockerfile for each step and reuse them in next steps.

for example, if you want to install postgres db, and install wildfly in your image. You can start creating a Dockerfile for postgresDB only, and build it to make your-postgres docker image.
Then create another Dockerfile which reuse your-postgres image by

```
FROM your-postgres
.....
```

and so on...